# how to update data in distributed environment

Tags: hbase, distributed, distributed-computing

We have a website showing videos to our users running on multiple web servers in a distributed environment. We are going to introduce a new feature where we only show videos to our users that they have not seen before whenever they come online. This could lead to a scenario where a user first hits server1 and sees video1 and the second time come to server2 and should be shown anything but video1. This requires maintaing this state in the backend and updating it in real-time. We have enough traffic to rule out mysql for updating this information in real-time. After doing enough research, it seems like cassandra/hbase will be a good option for this kind of a problem with their good write throughput. Is there any other approach that can be taken or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why not stash a list of recently viewed videos in a cookie on the user's browser?

If you really need to store it in a backend system, HBase would be suitable; one row per user, with a column qualifier for each video they've seen. You can do a simple exists check to see if they've seen any video.

Comment: thanks. Any reason to pick hbase over cassandra in this scenario. We already have a cassandra cluster running and was wondering if we could use that.

Comment: You find this link useful. It compares HBase and Cassandra  beautifully : http://bigdatanoob.blogspot.in/2012/11/hbase-vs-cassandra.html